# Puppet ca list error, root cause: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=error: certificate verify failed (self signed certificate in certificate chain)

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, puppet, foreman

Does anybody know how to fix it. I'm trying to check certificate requests on my foreman/puppet server and get this: Fatal error when running action 'list' Error: Failed connecting to https://xxxxxxx:8140/puppet-ca/v1/certificate_statuses/any_key?state=requested Root cause: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=error: certificate verify failed (self signed certificate in certificate chain)

Any ideas how to fix it and make it work? Thanks in advance

Comment: The error seems pretty self explanatory. What is unclear about it, what have you tried, and which chain of certs are you sending?

Comment: I'd like to mention again that this happens on the puppet server (master) side when I run 'puppetserver ca list' command to list cert requests from agents. I am confused because the server throws an error for it's own certificates. I mean the https://xxxxxxx:8140 (in the error description) and the host where I run the command are the same server. I tried reissuing all puppet server certificates by deleting them and running 'puppetserver ca setup' and got this error again. To be honest I don't have quite a big knowledge about certificates yet.

Comment: I don't understand what's wrong, given I have all of these components and certificates on the same machine and correctly mentioned in the puppet.conf file. Why puppet doesn't accept it's own self-signed certificate in this case? And how can I go around that? @MaartenBodewes

Comment: I'm not an expert on puppet by any stretch, but generally the idea is that you need to include the certificates that you trust in a *trust store*. This should include self-signed certificates (as you don't want to trust self-signed certificates from an adversary, of course). Self signed leaf certs are a bit weird, as they are their own trust anchor. Maybe it is better to create a chain for the best amount of compatibility.

Comment: By default, Puppet's CA creates and uses a self-signed certificate.  In that case, there is a self-signed certificate in the certificate chain of every cert it signs.   This is not normally a problem, and I'm not sure offhand why it is causing an issue for you.  I don't know exactly what would cause such breakage, but if it isn't a configuration change then it is likely a change in libssl or one of the other libraries on which Puppet relies.